# How do I get Logic to export the sounds recorded from Kontak w/ Symphobia?

Tags: logic-pro, sampling

I can get the sounds recorded and on separate tracks but they wont export.  It just says there is nothing to export.

Also I cant get Kontak in a regular channel strip with level meter. It will only come up in aux channels and then there is no control thru the master out, and if Kontak is closed after recording then there is no sound at all.  The tracks have the midi "notes" there.  I've tried importing the actual Symphobia samples but so far that hasn't helped.

I'm running logic on a MAC G5 OSx dual 2.3ghz

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: what version of Kontakt, Logic, and OSX are you using?

Comment: you could try soloing the tracks and bouncing.